# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Background service (worker service) Сразу отмечу, что интерполяция у строк соблюдена, и в дебаге, и при публикации запускаемый exe-шник работают. Только запускаю как сервис винды - выдает ошибку. Путь существует. Как настроить сервис для доступа к сетевому диску?

Comment: "Не удалось найти часть пути" - это все, что мы имеем, как думаете, по этой информации возможно дать ответ? Вот вы встаньте на наше место, на место незнакомых людей, к которым пришел незнакомец, который что-то там делаем (чего вы не знаем), это незнакомец говорит "ОШИБКА, как решить?" не давая нам ничего, что может помочь, даже кода нет, вызывающего данную ошибку. Вот как вы поступите в данной ситуации? Наверно подумаете "странный человек" и пройдете мимо, может поставите минус, а может еще проголосуете за закрытие вопроса (как того требует SO). Ну так может всеж дадите информацию, код, путь?

Comment: максимум что можно сделать, исходя из "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686917/c-system-io-directorynotfoundexception-could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path"(первая в гугле) - попробуй добавить `@` в путь

Comment: @EvgeniyZ здесь код как раз таки не нужен, это был общий вопрос про доступ к файлам на сетевом диске для сервиса

Comment: @Valeriy Даже про сетевой диск информации не было в вопросе, о чем вы... Не, ну если считаете это нормальным вопросом, дело ваше, удачи в поиске информации.

Comment: Сервис винды запущен из-под аккаунта, который не имеет доступа к файловой системе - такой ответ напрашивается из информации, содержащейся в теле вопроса. / Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив информацию про сетевой диск.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в неполном названии сетевого диска. Нужно прописать команду `use net` в командной строке, где и находится полное название (у меня это \\berta\nuoke\Somefolder , а не как я указывал \\berta\Somefolder). Также нужно ввести свои учетные данные (вход в систему) в свойствах службы для корректного доступа к сетевому диску